# GtkScale Widget

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to implement some Gtk Scale slider widgets.

My problem is that I can't actually get the sliders to be able to be dragged. I know this seems like it should be really obvious, but I can't figure out how to do it. Through googling I found some function `gtk_range_set_update_policy()`, which seems promising but no longer exists in the documentation. Searching through the documentation for scale widget and range widget, I can't find any function that makes the `slider` draggable (seems like it should be draggable by default).

PS: As a side question, what is "page_increment" and "page_size" in GtkAdjustment? The documentation simply describes them as "the page increment" and "the page size".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: just set an adjustment with `lower` and `upper` values. Don't experiment in C, it is slooow to write in. Use whatever scripting language you prefer, e.g. Python:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window ()
scale  = Gtk.Scale ()

scale.props.adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment (0, 0, 100)
# That's it ^^^^^^^^^^

window.add (scale)
window.show_all ()

window.set_size_request (400, 100)
window.present ()
window.connect ('destroy', lambda *ignored: Gtk.main_quit ())

Gtk.main ()
```

Edit: `page_increment` will affect the step by `Page Up`/`Page Down` keys. `page_size` is only used in scrollbars, as I understand.

Comment: Hmmm.. I have to write this in C, and I've never used Python before. I will try and see if change the bounds works!

Comment: It's understandable if you need to write in C, but it will pay off to learn a scripting language if only for quick experimenting.